# Get value of <select> on change

Tags: html, angular

I have the following code:

component.html:

```
<select id="select" (change)="selectInputUpdate(this.value)">
      <option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions" value="{{option .Id}}" class="select-option"></option>
</select>
```

component.ts:

```
selectInputUpdate(newVal: number){
        this.selectVal = newVal;
    }
```

I can get the `(change)` event to fire off fine, but I can't seem to pass in the value of the select. I can get the value from jquery or vanilla JS by selecting the  by ID, but I can't seem to do it more elegantly in-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select id="select" (change)="selectInputUpdate($event.target.value)">
      <option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions" value="{{option .Id}}" class="select-option"></option>
</select>
```

or

```
<select id="select" [(ngModel)]="selectedInput">
      <option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions" [ngValue]="option" class="select-option"></option>
</select>
```